# php the best way to return empty value

Tags: php, wordpress, html-table, advanced-custom-fields

I am filling a **WordPress** HTML table using WordPress **ACF plugin** and this function:(I think it is a **general PHP question**)

```
add_shortcode('custom_acf',custom_acf_callback);
function custom_acf_callback ($atts = '')
  {
  $value = shortcode_atts( array(
    'my_field' => '',
   ), $atts );
 //the main part starts from here:
   if ($custom_acf_value){

        return $custom_acf_value;
    }
    else {
//and the problem is here:
        return '';
    }
```

and I am hiding the empty table cells using this tricky css code:

```
td:empty {
display: none;
}
```

The **Problem** is that the empty cells will not be hidden because the table cells have a default value that is my shortcode, I tried using:

```
return NULL;
```

and also simply using "return" but they are not return empty in table cells.Note that the **css** is tested separately and works with no problem, How can I return a  real **empty** value?

Comment: How about returning an empty array like `return array()` or `return []` ping me if it worked to move into a full answer.

Comment: How does the "default value" end up in the table cell if you return "true" empty values?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas thak you but it does not work becuse cannot handle the array and prints "array()" string in the table cell

Comment: How about not using else block? What does that do?

Comment: @Manjunath no difference and not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching some days, suddenly I saw there is a unwanted **`<br>`** in empty cells and I don't know why.
after that I have tested this code to prevent **`<br>`** in table cells, the code now is somthing like this but not exactly and works good:

```
$my_empty = "";
$my_nobr = strip_tags($my_empty, '<p><a>');
return $my_nobr;
```

I guess the reason is in **WordPress**  functions but I did not go deeper and there was no need, this code solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_shortcode('custom_acf',custom_acf_callback);

function custom_acf_callback ($atts = '')
{
  $value = shortcode_atts( array(
    'my_field' => '',
  ), $atts );

  // the main part starts from here:
  if ($custom_acf_value) {
    return $custom_acf_value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check the return value, before using the method `add_shortcode`:

```
$value = custom_acf_callback();

if($value){
    add_shortcode('custom_acf', $value);
} else {
    add_shortcode(); // not sure what this method does and if you need it to generate empty cells?
}
```

Comment: it does not work because the shortcodes are already in table cells so if you do not use add_shortcode, the cells will not be empty

Comment: shortcodes are in html table file for example <td>[custom_acf]</td>